# Why won't devise update an attribute in my DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

We have copy / pasted the Devise registrations controller and some of it's methods to tweak things.  Normal.

The update method looks like this:

```
def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)
    ap account_update_params
    resource_updated = resource.update_attributes(account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

I put the ap account_update_params in there to ensure that I'm getting all the right stuff before update:

```
{
             "email" => "email@address.com",
        "first_name" => "Foo",
         "last_name" => "Bar",
         "user_type" => "1",
           "company" => "Company",
             "phone" => "555-555-5555",
        "temp_units" => "c",
    "volume_measure" => "0",
         "address_1" => "1234 Anywhere Ln",
         "address_2" => "",
              "city" => "Somewhere",
          "province" => "CA",
            "postal" => "90210",
        "country_id" => "201"
}
```

Yup, they're all there.

Here's the issue:  temp_units and volume_measure NEVER get updated.

Model:

```
attr_accessible :email,
                  :password,
                  :password_confirmation,
                  :remember_me,
                  :temp_units,
                  :first_name,
                  :last_name,
                  :company,
                  :address_1,
                  :address_2,
                  :city,
                  :province,
                  :postal,
                  :phone,
                  :country_id,
                  :volume_measure,
                  :user_type
```

They're accessible - and all the OTHER params get updated just fine.  Only these two aren't being touched.

Why

Comment: Do you have any validation in the model that could prevent the update?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not Devise at all.

Someone else had checked in this nice little tid-bit:

```
  # This is used after user creation.
  # If the user is from USA it will set the user's
  # default locale to inferior measurement units.
  def set_locale
    if [201, 200].include?(self.country_id)
      self.temp_units = "f"
      self.volume_measure = User::VOLUME_MEASURE_GALLONS
    else
      self.temp_units = "c"
      self.volume_measure = User::VOLUME_MEASURE_LITERS
    end
  end
```

And nested somewhere near the top of the model:

```
  before_save :set_locale # Changed from after_save.
```

...